# Hitting enter results in KDB background process stopping

Tags: linux, bash, kdb, q-lang

I am running a [Kx Q process](http://code.kx.com/q/learn/) on my Linux server

I notice that when I run this command that after I hit return/enter on my shell that the process stops

```
./kdb/q/l32/q -p 1234 &
```

However, if I run this in the foreground...

```
./kdb/q/l32/q -p 1234
```

It opens up a q) prompt that hitting return/enter does not cause it to exit

I am wondering if hitting enter causing the process to stop is something related to Kx, or if its Linux related?

Any advice is appreciated

Comment: A background process trying to read from the terminal will be suspended. Is there a daemon or background or headless option to run it as a service? I did a quick search and found `-s slaves for parallel execution` which doesn't seem quite right, but your basic problem is trying to read from the terminal. In the foreground that is not a problem, but in the background it will suspend and wait for you to bring it to the foreground so you can respond to the prompt.

Comment: Thanks @StephenP. The strange thing is though is that it will work fine in the background but once I hit enter it stops

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use [nohup](https://linux.101hacks.com/unix/nohup-command/) to execute the command in background.
For example

```
nohup ./kdb/q/l32/q -p 1234 &
```